# Selecting explicit cells from pd.DataFrame via .at with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am having a MultiIndex based pd.DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), 0)],
           names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
```

Now I want to replace the cells with a list object (type cast the DataFrame to object before):

```py
idx = data.index[0]
data.at[idx, 'temp'] = [1,2,3]
```

This will yield to:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/app/generic_model/modules/feature_engineering/lstm_pre_processing.py in <module>
----> 1 data.at[idx, 'temp']

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2151             # GH#33041 fall back to .loc
   2152             if not isinstance(key, tuple) or not all(is_scalar(x) for x in key):
-> 2153                 raise ValueError("Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!")
   2154             return self.obj.loc[key]
   2155 

ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!
```

I do not know what the problem is, because using `.loc` works fine. But with `.loc` I am not able to replace the cell value. The error message is not really helpful in this case.

I am running `pd.__version__: 1.2.2` on python 3.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can still use `loc` to assign the single cell value by creating the intermediate series having the same index corresponding to the cell that needs to be updated. As a side note, storing complex objects in pandas columns is generally not a good practice as you will loose the benefits of vectorization.

```
data.loc[idx, 'temp'] = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3]], index=[idx])
```

---

```
                                                               temp  temp_2
dt_calc             dt_fore             positional_index                   
2019-07-01 23:00:00 2019-07-01 23:00:00 0                 [1, 2, 3]       3
2019-07-02 00:00:00 2019-07-02 00:00:00 0                         4       5
                                        0                         6       7
2019-07-02 01:00:00 2019-07-02 01:00:00 0                         8       9
2019-07-02 02:00:00 2019-07-02 02:00:00 0                        10      11
2019-07-02 03:00:00 2019-07-02 03:00:00 0                        12      13
```

Comment: I am with you, but I need this for pre processing data to use in LSTM. Vectorization is not possible from my actual point of view. Because I am having data with multiple dt_fore for each dt_calc and the sequences should not overlap between different dt_calc.

Comment: Great, I had tried Series, but I missed the index! +1

Comment: nice ..this sparks a question in my mind that I will ask seperately as a new question +1

Comment: Here is a new question about the origin of my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790442/lstm-rnn-pre-processing-on-multiindex-dataframe-with-forecast-data