# LSTM/RNN pre processing on MultiIndex DataFrame with forecast data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

RNN and LSTM requires to define sequences for each feature data point.

Forecast data (e.g. weather forecast) are characterized by having a calculation timestamp and a forecast timestamp (here `dt_calc` and `dt_fore`). Such data could yield to a dataframe like this:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [9, 8], [8, 9], [5, 4], [3, 3]],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 04:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 04:00:00'), 0)
                    ],
                        names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
```

For a sequence length of 2 a dataset to use in LSTM or RNN should look like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[[2, 4], [3, 5]], [[4, 6], [5, 7]], [[6, 8], [7, 9]], [[8, 10], [9, 11]], [[12, 9], [13, 8]], [[9, 8], [8, 9]], [[8, 5], [9, 4]], [[5, 3], [4, 3]]],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 04:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 04:00:00'), 0)
                    ],
                        names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
```

And here for sequence length 3:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame([[[2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]], [[4, 6, 8], [5, 7, 9]], [[6, 8, 10], [7, 9, 11]], [[12, 9, 8], [13, 8, 9]], [[9, 8, 5], [8, 9, 4]], [[8, 5, 3], [9, 4, 3]]],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 04:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 04:00:00'), 0)
                    ],
                        names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
```

This dataframe can be transformed to a numpy array with sequences easiely.

The importance within this question is to take care about the timestamps because a sequence is defined by a time period and not by index in this case.

EDIT:
After a good suggestion by Shubham Sharma: I will outline another example to clarify the importance of taking the timestamps into account. because in case of irregular intervals in dt_fore it come to the following input:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [9, 8], [8, 9], [5, 4], [3, 3]],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 04:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 04:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 05:00:00'), 0)
                    ],
                        names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
```

This should restructured for LSTM/RNN use with n=2 to:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame([[[2, 4], [3, 5]], [[4, 6], [5, 7]], [[6, 8], [7, 9]], [[8, 10], [9, 11]], [[12, 9], [13, 8]], [[9, 8], [8, 9]],[[5, 3], [4, 3]]],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 03:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 04:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 01:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 02:00:00'), 0),
                        (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-04 05:00:00'), 0)
                    ],
                        names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
```

Comment: Can you please show the expected output for sequence of length `3`?

Comment: This should be the output for sequence length 3:

Answer (score 0):

We can define a generator function which groups the dataframe by the `dt_calc` column and uses the rolling operation with window of size `n` to aggregate the columns to list thereby yielding sequences.

```
def seq(n):
    df = data.reset_index()
    for g in df.groupby('dt_calc', sort=False).rolling(n):
        yield g[data.columns].to_numpy().T if len(g) == n else []

pd.DataFrame(seq(2), index=data.index, columns=data.columns).dropna()
```

---

```
# n=2
                                                    temp   temp_2
dt_calc    dt_fore             positional_index                  
2019-07-02 2019-07-02 01:00:00 0                  [2, 4]   [3, 5]
           2019-07-02 02:00:00 0                  [4, 6]   [5, 7]
           2019-07-02 03:00:00 0                  [6, 8]   [7, 9]
           2019-07-02 04:00:00 0                 [8, 10]  [9, 11]
2019-07-04 2019-07-04 01:00:00 0                 [12, 9]  [13, 8]
           2019-07-04 02:00:00 0                  [9, 8]   [8, 9]
           2019-07-04 03:00:00 0                  [8, 5]   [9, 4]
           2019-07-04 04:00:00 0                  [5, 3]   [4, 3]

# n=3
                                                       temp      temp_2
dt_calc    dt_fore             positional_index                        
2019-07-02 2019-07-02 02:00:00 0                  [2, 4, 6]   [3, 5, 7]
           2019-07-02 03:00:00 0                  [4, 6, 8]   [5, 7, 9]
           2019-07-02 04:00:00 0                 [6, 8, 10]  [7, 9, 11]
2019-07-04 2019-07-04 02:00:00 0                 [12, 9, 8]  [13, 8, 9]
           2019-07-04 03:00:00 0                  [9, 8, 5]   [8, 9, 4]
           2019-07-04 04:00:00 0                  [8, 5, 3]   [9, 4, 3]
```

Comment: This works pretty fast but it requires equal weighted intervals as you define n in rolling with an integer. It would be nice to have an interval like '3H'  but rolling requires integer in that case. In general using generator function is a good deal. I will work on that.

Comment: Its possible to pass the offset frequency in rolling function, but in that case the length of sequences would vary for example if you use the frequency as `3H` the first two sequences for the column `temp` would be `[2], [2, 4]`

Comment: Then it would be the best way to fill possible gaps with nan, apply the generator function and drop all entries with nan ?